# How do I make the tab-key expand abbreviations for emmet in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, ide

I have installed [emmet](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-eclipse) plugin for eclipse and it works fine. The problem is that I couldn't enable the tab key to expand the abbreviation.

It writes the normal tab white space, I searched a a lot but I couldn't find the solution.

Please advise.

Comment: Please give us screenshots or more information to help you better

Comment: Which version of Eclipse? Are you sure Emmet works properly with that version? Have you tried restoring defaults for Emmet in case you changed some setting by mistake?

Comment: I'm using Version: 4.2.1, yes it's supported according http://docs.emmet.io/#supported-editors, no changed settings. I have another question how to delete a  key shortcut in eclipse? I know about unbind but i want to remove the entire record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. I believe I have not touched the setting, but I don't know why the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key does not work. I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> instead and it worked for me.

Comment: You can also use the below link as a reference https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#tab-key-handler

Comment: As per https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#tab-key-handler, tab will only work in limited syntax scopes (HTML, XML, HAML, CSS, SASS/SCSS, LESS and strings in programming languages (like JavaScript, Python, Ruby etc.). In other scopes, you need to use ctrl+e. Someone without ability to edit tried to edit that in and I'm just posting it here. Not sure if it's correct or anything else about it.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably trying to expand abbreviation in a file type that is not listed in Emmet settings, like jsp.
After installing Emmet in Eclipse you can go Window->Preferences->Emmet and add *jsp* to "*…in files with extensions*" box.
After that Tab key will expand abbreviations in jsp files.
Eclipse 4.5.2

Answer (score 0):

> By default, Tab handler works in a limited *syntax scopes*: HTML, XML,
>   HAML, CSS, SASS/SCSS, LESS and *strings in programming languages*
>   (like JavaScript, Python, Ruby etc.). It means:
>
> - You have to switch your document to one of the syntaxes listed above to expand abbreviations by Tab key.
> - With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> shortcut, you can expand abbreviations everywhere, its scope is not limited.

-- [Tab key handler](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#tab-key-handler)

Answer (score 0):

I can resolve the problem in my notepad++ version 6.7.9.2. 
In Notepad++ open **Settings** menu, open **Shortcut Mapper** sub-menu then choose **Pluggin commands** tab. Search for Expand abbreviation and double-click it. Uncheck all check-boxes and choose Tab in the combo-box.
Clik Ok button followed by Close button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want emmet to work with jsp files, do the following:

1. In eclipse click on window
   [image]
2. then click on preferences
   [image]
3. In preferences window click on emmet
   [image]
4. inside emmet click on field which says ...in files with extension
   [image]
5. add ', jsp' to it
   [image]
6. make sure 'expand abbreviations with tab key' is checked
   [image]
7. hit Apply
   [image]
8. and now hit ok
   [image]

Now you are good to use emmet abbreviations in jsp file.
To test it out create a jsp file, name it anything.
then type '!' and hit tab key. It should create a blank html template.
Hope this helps.